# Duplicate contact storages

Tags: contacts

I use Android 2.3.4 (Gingerbread).

When I go to Contacts > [MENU] > Display options, I see duplicate entries as "bud***@gmail.com Phone-only (unsynced)". *(1) See left image.*

And when I try to add a new contact, I face the same issue. *(2) See right image.*

[image: Screen Shoots]

Why does this happen? This wasn't there earlier and I noticed this right now. I didn't visit contacts app recently though. I noticed this when I tried to add a new contact.

Adding more to the issue, I can create new contacts and save them inside one of these places, but it'll always display in the bottom duplicate. Even if I select the top duplicate when saving, it'll only display in the bottom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weird problem had a weird solution. I turned the phone off and turned it on again, and the problem was gone.

I can't give any reason as to why the problem occurred and why it got solved. Might be a bug.

Comment: On a side note, I look silly here, not doing a turn-off-on at the first place. But why all that happened?!